# Clock that sign different time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

I have a problem understanding this example:
There is a set of clocks, far away from me and spatially distant from each other and they are synchronized in the frame in which they are all stationary. I'm also at rest with respect to the clocks and I see, with a telescope, that the clocks show different time. Why? If, they are all at rest why I don't see the same time for all the clocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not have taken into consideration that light travels with a finite speed.
This means that the light from the more distant clocks will reach you later and thus show an earlier time than the clocks that are closer to you.

Comment: Thank you very much! Hence this mean that this example has nothing to do with time dilation, length contraction nor the relativity of simultaneity, doesn't it?

Comment: Precisely, it's just a timing issue.